# Facebook Like Button Generates Totally Generic Links, Despite Description and Image Showing Up Correctly in Debugger

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbml, feed

I've implemented the Facebook like button on my site, but "liked" links are showing up totally generically in the News Feed.

[image: generic news feed]

There's no description, no title, no source domain, and no image.

Compare, for example, a liking of an IMDB entry:

[image: imdb]

Which has the image, description, and source domain.

This is strange to me, because I've followed the description for their meta tags, and used their "linter" / debugger, where everything looks just fine:

[image: debugger]

Here you can clearly see that Facebook's own debugger is finding the image (the purple blob), and the description.

So why isn't that making it to the News Feed?  Any ideas?

Comment: What is the url for the like? Is it **exactly** the same as the one you debugged?

Comment: As far as I am aware, yes—you can see in the images that the URL being "liked" in the topmost image is the same URL listed in the debugger.  Any ideas?

Comment: Nitzan, I checked it out. Turns out that Rails changed the functionality of url_for to default to relative path, and so the FB like button links were relative URLS, without the http://inknode.com domain. Facebook was smart enough to fill in the domain, but for some reason it was breaking the Open Graph tags.  Changed it to the full path and it worked.  Thank you so much! This had been stumping me for weeks.  If you want to put your suggestion as an answer, I'll checkmark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook is very picky with the urls since they index the pages by that.

Make sure that the url for the like button is **exactly** as the one you used in the debugger, since there everything worked as planned.